# Error : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

From past 3 days I am stuck in the same issue of signature. I am not understanding how to come out of this.

I am trying to get a pre signed url with this :

```
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject',
    event.pre_signed_url =    
           {Bucket:config.awsBucket,Key:event.filename}
      ); in Node js.
```

And this pre signed url I am using to upload the image file in the s3 bucket by using :

```
   request({
      method:'PUT',
      url: event.pre_signed_url,
      ContentType: 'image/png',
      body: fs.createReadStream('./image.png')}
      , function(err, res, body)
   { if(err)console.log(err); return callback(body); }
  );
```

And the file is getting successfully uploaded to the s3 bucket and I can see in aws s3 bucket console.

The issue is that the pre-signed url that I am getting if I am trying to PUT any other image file using curl from terminal or trying to open the url in the browser it is giving me signature mis match error.

Please guide me if I am doing wrong or my understanding with pre signed url usage is wrong.

Comment: Solved : I was actually making get request to the url returned from s3.getSignedUrl('putObject',) but  to view the sceenshot in s3 bucket after uploading I must check the presigned url of s3.getSignedUrl('getObject') to view the screenshot

Comment: This was my problem too.  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll happily upvote.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem while using `S3.getSignedUrl('putObject'`, serverside, and then trying to use that url clientside. You are setting an extra header on the request that is not being set in the params.

What I noticed in my case, which might be relevant to yours, is that signatures created with all the `S3.getSignedUrl` take into account request headers. So if you are generating a URL, it will fail with the same error message you received unless sent with the same headers.

One example of a failure: Generated like this..

```
var params = { Bucket: 'YourBucket', Key: 'uniqueFileKey', Expires: 10000 };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }
      return cb(null, url)
    });
```

The following request fails when a using that same url generated. This request was made from a browser.

```
RequestMethod: Put
Headers: {
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:11768
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
}
```

And the difference is that the signature above created doesn't include content-type, where the request does specify a content-type. Params need to match headers, or the error thrown will be signature doesn't match.

Successful example below:

```
var params = { Bucket: 'YourBucket', Key: 'uniqueFileKey', Expires: 10000, Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }
      return cb(null, url)
    });
```

Comment: It's now `ContentType` and not `Content-Type`